# How can I use xpath in Selenium RC by using Java

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, selenium-rc

My application has the following snippet of code:

```
<form id="frmDepartmentCreation" name="frmDepartmentCreation" method="post" 
      action="">
    <table class="formStyle_1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" 
            width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left"><label class="formBtn_1">
                <input  id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" type="submit" 
                        onclick="return val()"/></label>
                <input type="hidden" name="hdnbutton" id="hdnbutton" value=""/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

What is the xpath of "Submit" button considering the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need XPath and I wouldn't recommend using xpath in this situation. In this case id can be used as below:

```
selenium.click("id=Submit");
```

The above code would do what you want.

Comment: Agreed. XPath is less readable (and by that measure, less maintainable)...I am partial towards using CSS. XPath, however, is useful for tables.

Comment: Yes, If there is ID available it's better to use id instead of xpath. css path is faster than xpath

Comment: simple xpath for Submit button is as follows: //input[@id = 'Submit']

Answer (score 0):

`//form[@id = 'frmDepartmentCreation']//input[@id = 'Submit']` is one way (starting with `//` is done as I assume that snippets is part of a larger document.

Comment: +1 Correct. Altough given a DTD declaring `@id` of type `ID`, one could use `id('Submit')`

Comment: Right, I thought about using `id` but with the question being tagged as selenium rc I was not sure that is supported so I went with the posted expression.

Comment: Your xpath is right. But, it is not a good practice to use this sort of long xpath. The better to use only //input[@id='Submit']